# How to sum even or odd numbers in a list given the condition odd or even?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

So the problem is asking me to return the sum of even or odd elements in a list given the condition odd or even. So if the condition is odd, I have to return a list of all odd numbers. If the list is blank/the values do not match the condition, then return 0.

This is what I have so far:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def conditionalSum(value, condition):
    s = 0
    if condition == "even":
        for i in l:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                s += i
    elif condition == "odd":
        for i in l:
            if i % 2 !=0:
                s = s+ i
    else:
        return 0
```

When I try to run this, nothing comes up - not even an error! Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where do you return `s`?

Comment: If you unconditionally `return s` at the end of the function (which will fix the main problem), then you don't actually need the `else` block because `0` will get returned if neither the `if` or `elif` blocks are entered.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code can be modified to be more pythonic using a built-in `sum` function.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def conditionalSum(value, condition):
    if condition == "even":
        return sum(i for i in l if i % 2 == 0)

    elif condition == "odd":
        return sum(i for i in l if i % 2 == 1)

    else:
        return 0

print(conditionalSum(value, "even"))
```

Output:

```
12
```

---

btw you have an unused variable `value` in your function `conditionalSum`

Comment: Nice, however I find `i % 2 == 0` and then `i % 2 != 0` a bit "confusing", also this approach won't work if using other modulus. I prefer explicitly checking  `== 0` and `== 1` for consistency.

Comment: thank you for adding this, I am actually practicing these generator expressions right now so this is great

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I've updated the answer.

Comment: yep, removed the s=0 statement and edited it to include the unused variable "value"

Comment: There is something wrong about the function as it currently stands, though. You are ignoring the parameter `value` passed to it, and instead using the `l` variable taken from an outer scope. In fact the output shown is _not_ of the code as it currently stands - which would raise a `NameError` in the attempted function call (`value` is never assigned).

Comment: @alaniwi you're correct. the output calculated was from the different arguments. I changed the arguments int the answer just for the sake of the presentation.

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to call the fonction: conditionalSum(l, "even") for instance
2. you don't return any value for the 2 conditions "even" and "odd". Corrected code:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def conditionalSum(value, condition):
    s = 0
    if condition == "even":
        for i in value:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                s += i
    elif condition == "odd":
        for i in value:
            if i % 2 !=0:
                s += i
    return s

print(conditionalSum(l,"even"))
print(conditionalSum(l,"odd"))
```